# getGL2() method of GL interface can not find in netbeans

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, netbeans-8

I am trying to create a 3D cube in netbeans using OpenGL plugins(0.5.5) and facing some errors like `can not find symbol method getGL2() from GL interface`. I have searched a lot on the web but still can't solve the error.

Code producing error as follows:

```
final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
```

Comment: Hi Misal, don't use that plugin, it is outdated. Set up a project like [here](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#NetBeans_IDE).

Comment: elect is right, the abandoned Netbeans OpenGL Pack stopped been maintained several years ago, it was based on an old version of JOGL.